# Cannot resolve constructor Intent(..ExpL,<java.lang.class....Lon>)

Tags: android, android-intent, onclick, onclicklistener

I am trying to send the user to a different activity with intent on button click. But right now this code says `Cannot resolve constructor Intent(..,java.lang.class<..>)`

Here is my code:

```
item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(i == 1) {
            Intent i = new Intent(ExpL.this, Lon.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Your code looks alright... Have a look at your import statements. How does the import look like for the Intent class?

Comment: `import android.content.Intent;`, perhaps it is because I extend `RecycleView` on my activity

Comment: If your ExpL class is not an Activity or any other way wraps a context you can't use it to start an Activity. See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html. You could add a context to your RecyclerView or get one from class that extends the View class.

Comment: My ExpL is class, and whta to you mean get one from class that extends the View class?

Comment: A class extending the View class always has a Context. RecyclerView is not extending the View class, but your layout might. You might have a TextView in your class for instance. Or check if your ‘item‘ has the method ‘get context()‘...

Comment: Yes indeed my item has method get context(), but even if I add `item.getContext();` before the clickListener nothing changes

Comment: What is "i" variable use in if statement (if(i == 1)) ?

Answer (score 3):

If you are starting another activity from fragment try

```
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), NextActivity.class);
```

if you are starting activity from activity try

```
Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), NextActivity.class);
```

make sure the NextActivity class extends any Activity Class i.e in your case Lon is a Activity

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), MyClass.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer. I had extended RecycleView in my activity which means that I cannot extend activity and so the intent did not work.

Comment: That is not true. You can always start an `Intent` from any place where you have a `Context`. It's common to add a `Context` to a `RecyclerView` or your `View` that is wrapped in the `ViewHolder` will also have a `Context`.
However, if the class you want to transition to, is not an `Activity` then it might not work.

Comment: I think the last part is what it is :p